# How to send [ ] as string in JSON?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

In a particular scenario I want to send the INI file contents as JSON Data .

This is my Sample Content, that I want to `json_encode` in PHP Codeigniter.

```
[PRODUCT]
Username=9008
Password=45645646464654

[DialPlan]
DP_Exception=
DP_Rule1=
DP_Rule2=

[Advanced]
CellNumber=
Transport=
isAccountActive=1

[Device]
VirtualMAC=
ToolReset=
Mode=3"
```

I tried this way :

```
 $message =  array(
"Request" =>"AddUpdateBaseINI",
"GMT_Timestamp"=>$timestamp,
"SessionID"=>$session_id,
"tenant_id" =>"1",
"INI"=>"[PRODUCT]
Username=9008
Password=45645646464654

[DialPlan]
DP_Exception=
DP_Rule1=
DP_Rule2=

[Advanced]
CellNumber=
Transport=
isAccountActive=1

[Device]
VirtualMAC=
ToolReset=
Mode=3"

);

$request = json_encode($message);
```

But this does not produce the expected outcome.
How Do I pass "[ ]" as string and not json object.

**Expected Output**:

```
{
  "Request": "GetDefaultBaseINI",
  "GMT_Timestamp": "055110",
  "SessionID": "79r46pobm2ah2pk4bjnqs2f5k9g2ubjn",
  "INI": "[PRODUCT] Username=9008 Password=45645646464654 [DialPlan] DP_Exception= DP_Rule1= DP_Rule2= [Advanced] CellNumber= Transport= isAccountActive=1 [Device] VirtualMAC= ToolReset= Mode=3"
}
```

**Output I get $_POST []:**

Array ( `[{"Request":"AddUpdateBaseINI","GMT_Timestamp":"064024","SessionID":"79r46pobm2ah2pk4bjnqs2f5k9g2ubjn","tenant_id":"1","INIID":null,"location_id":"2","product":"bizfms","INIContent":"] => Array ( [BIZFMS] => 9008 Password=45645646464654 Domain=172.24.130.201 Proxy=172.24.130.122 Port=5070 SipAuthName=45645646464654 DisplayName=Jayesh SiteKey=5DCA-E878 Proxy=172.24.130.122 [DialPlan]DP_Exception= DP_Rule1= DP_Rule2= [Advanced] EnterpriseVoiceMail= EnterpriseVoiceMailPin= CellNumber= SipTransport=\r\nDNSServer= 8.8.8.8 EnableDNS= RegistrationExpiry=3600 DTMFMode=\r\nKeepAliveWiFi=30 KeepAliveMobileData=60SipDSCP=30 RTPDSCP=28 SecureRTP=\r\nClientSipPort=5090 ConnectivityMode=1 WiFiDisconnectionAlert= StunServer= EnableIce= HoldType= Codec=9,8,0 MobileDataCodecs=9,8,0 PacketizationInterval=20 SoftwareAEC= EchoTailLength=300 ToneLocalization= EnableVideo=1 VideoFrame=9 InitialBitrate=500 MaximumBitrate= 1000 VideoResolution=1 VideoPort=19304 LogLevel=60000 RunInBackground=1 EdOption=1 EnsipOption=3 RingTone= DefaultisAccountActive=1 [Device]VirtualMAC= ToolReset=\r\nAudioMode= 3"} ) [0] => Array ( [BIZFMS] => 9008 Password=45645646464654 Domain=172.24.130.201 Proxy=172.24.130.122 Port=5070 SipAuthName=45645646464654 DisplayName=Jayesh SiteKey=5DCA-E878 Proxy=172.24.130.122 [DialPlan]DP_Exception= DP_Rule1= DP_Rule2= [Advanced] EnterpriseVoiceMail= EnterpriseVoiceMailPin= CellNumber= SipTransport=\r\nDNSServer= 8.8.8.8 EnableDNS= RegistrationExpiry=3600 DTMFMode=\r\nKeepAliveWiFi=30 KeepAliveMobileData=60SipDSCP=30 RTPDSCP=28 SecureRTP=\r\nClientSipPort=5090 ConnectivityMode=1 WiFiDisconnectionAlert= StunServer= EnableIce= HoldType= Codec=9,8,0 MobileDataCodecs=9,8,0 PacketizationInterval=20 SoftwareAEC= EchoTailLength=300 ToneLocalization= EnableVideo=1 VideoFrame=9 InitialBitrate=500 MaximumBitrate= 1000 VideoResolution=1 VideoPort=19304 LogLevel=60000 RunInBackground=1 EdOption=1 EnsipOption=3 RingTone= DefaultisAccountActive=1 [Device]VirtualMAC= ToolReset=\r\nAudioMode= 3"} ) )`

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: Please explain more on this `How Do I pass "[ ]" as string and not json object` ?

Comment: I have added the expected output @JYoThI

Comment: @Niklesh i am unable to explain exactly but i can tell that i want to send this as [PRODUCT] not as an array because on server side when i decode the json it takes [PRODUCT] as array

Comment: Check this its working :  https://eval.in/777401

Comment: And what is the output you get? And why isn't that the output you expected. At the frist look everything looks fine to me.

Comment: it's encoding properly while decode it outputing as string as you expected . "[PRODUCT] Username=9008 Password=45645646464654 [DialPlan] DP_Exception= DP_Rule1= DP_Rule2=[Advanced] CellNumber=Transport=isAccountActive=1[Device]VirtualMAC=ToolReset=Mode=3" it did not consider as array .

Comment: okay I have added the output i get, can you please help me decode this JSON ???

Comment: Your expected output is not correct, because the newlines are replaced by spaces. But there's nothing special about `[]`.

Comment: Why am i getting this `Array ( [BIZFMS]` ?

Comment: Have you tried placing your code in a continuous string, it seems the slashes come from the start of your PRODUCT field. 
`[PRODUCT] Username=9008 Password=45645646464654 [DialPlan] DP_Exception= DP_Rule1= DP_Rule2= [Advanced] CellNumber= Transport= isAccountActive=1 [Device] VirtualMAC= ToolReset= Mode=3`

Comment: @JYoThI i send this using CURL request so when i try to decode the json i have first do ` $raw_data = array_keys($_POST); 
 $json_data = json_decode($raw_data[0]);` then i can use the data now in this case i cannot properly decode the data

Comment: @dalelandry i will try that in one line

Answer (score 1):

You need to used [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string method for pass `INI file` in your `JSON` like below :

```
$string = <<<EOD
[PRODUCT]
Username=9008
Password=45645646464654

[DialPlan]
DP_Exception=
DP_Rule1=
DP_Rule2=

[Advanced]
CellNumber=
Transport=
isAccountActive=1

[Device]
VirtualMAC=
ToolReset=
Mode=3
EOD;


$message =  array(
"Request" =>"AddUpdateBaseINI",
"GMT_Timestamp"=>$timestamp,
"SessionID"=>$session_id,
"tenant_id" =>"1",
"INI"=>"$string"
);

$request = json_encode($message);
echo $request;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($request,true));
```

Comment: There is no need of `<<<EOD` we can normally encode the string and decode it

Comment: @NishantNair OP want to pass `INI file` data in `JSON`, So he need to pass it as string. So its best method to pass multi line string.

Comment: No need of that it was getting properly encoded please check the comments. Also have a look at the response which he is expecting is same as my answer link

Comment: @NishantNair Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be escaped, but the escape codes listed above can still be used.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine

```
    <?php

     $message =  array(
    "Request" =>"AddUpdateBaseINI",
    "GMT_Timestamp"=>$timestamp,
    "SessionID"=>$session_id
    "tenant_id" =>"1",
    "INI"=>"[PRODUCT]
    Username=9008
    Password=45645646464654

    [DialPlan]
    DP_Exception=
    DP_Rule1=
    DP_Rule2=

    [Advanced]
    CellNumber=
    Transport=
    isAccountActive=1

    [Device]
    VirtualMAC=
    ToolReset=
    Mode=3"

    );

    echo json_encode($message);
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r(json_decode(json_encode($message),true));
```

https://eval.in/777403

Comment: I am sending this using CURL request to server how do i decode the same data ?

Comment: What exactly do you want from the json? Its getting parsed and encode perfectly with the array specified

Comment: Okay i got it that its getting encoded properly but how do i decode the same data ? can you please show me some sample code ? As I am using the CURL on server i have the json data in $_POST[]  now i want to decode the $_POST[]

Comment: is it the case that you are hitting the curl request and you are getting the response in json and now you need to decode it in your side

Comment: Always print the `$result = curl_exec($ch);` result of the curl. Accordingly you can check what is the response from the server. Depending upon that you can decode it

Comment: how do i decode this ? I have added in question what i get in $_POST

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141856/discussion-between-rajan-and-nishant-nair).